# sets and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, linear-transformations

Given a non empty set A, and B. Let f be a mapping from A to B. such that (a,f(a))  is an element of the space A X B , with a being an element of A and f(a) being an element of B. If I use methods of linear algebra, am i correct to say, a(1,0)+f(a)(0,1)=(a,f(a)), where (1,0) is the basis vector for the set A, and (0,1) is the basis vector for the set B.

Comment: How do you know $1$ and $0$ are elements of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: And how do you know that there's an operation of addition in $A$ and an operation of addition in $B$?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the person who asked this question will understand the concepts being presented in the comments. The question mentions "linear algebra" so presumably we take it that $A$ and $B$ are linear vector spaces, that is ones with elements 0 and 1 and addition and multiplication defined.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information missing in your post. This is not neccesaraily bad as people can interpret the missing parts. But if you don't mean them, then that could cause problems. For example, everyone will interpret that $A$ and $B$ are vector spaces over the same field $F$. If you mean that, then $f(a)$ and $a$ are vectors and not scalars. Thus, you cannot multiply them by a vector in $A$ and $B$ the way you did.

There is not much else I can say at the moment unless you provide more information. So, if this doesn't answer your question and you are asking about something else, please provide more information.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, that would be a correct way to frame the situation, assuming that scalar multiplication is defined on the sets $A$ and $B$. You could have a set $A$ or $B$ where multiplication was not defined, but that may be a detail you don't need to worry about.